# empty() not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, is-empty, cakephp-3.2

I have `products` table and want to select all products. 
This is what I have done

```
$products = $this->Products->find('all', [
   'conditions' => [
       'status' => 1
   ]
]);
$this->set('products', $products);
```

and print products if fetched and `No product found` when no product is retrieved.

This is what I have done for this

```
if (!empty($products)):
   // show products
else:
   echo 'No Products Found';
endif;
```

But this is not working, even if no product is found else condition is not printed.

If condition is not even working in controller action. Is there something missing ?

I'm using CakePHP 3.2

Comment: Have you tried to dump the content of `$products`?

Comment: do you mean `debug` ? If yes, Yes I tried to debug but there is no products. I tried even after emptying the table from `phpmyadmin` and even then it is not working

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using? You can't expect to get the appropriate assistance unless you provide these basic details..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for check content that is null or not use function `isEmpty()` in CakePHP 3.0.5

```
if (!$products->isEmpty()) {
   // show products  
}
else
   echo 'No Products Found';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if (!empty($products->toArray())):
   // show products
else:
   echo 'No Products Found';
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your cakephp is 3.0.5 or higher, read **ashkufaraz's** answer, else,  you can use:

```
if(count($products) > 0)
 {
     //Print ya products
 }
else
 {
    echo 'No products found';
 }
```